# How to automatically start Teapot on an Image start?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I use Teapot micro framework for my REST API server. However, if I reboot the VM Teapot does not start automatically on Image start.

What is the right way to autostart Teapot?

Comment: Teapot uses Zinc server, and simply feeds it with a special router. So if you know how to deal with Zinc it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways you can add startup scripts to a Pharo Image:

1) The most simple way is just to put a "startup.st" file into the  directory with the Image. This file is run after the Image is loaded so any configurations can be there. So for instance Teapot start can be run from there.

2) More advanced way is to use "Smalltalk addToStartUpList: MyClass" call. This method will register "MyClass" into SessionManager startupList so that "MyClass>>startUp" class method is called on Image start.

This means that MyClass must have "startUp" method defined on the class side (where init Teapot script could be put).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at how ZeroConf works. You can add a script that is executed when you start the image. The documentation on ZeroConf is on [ci](https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/DeepIntoPharo/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/tmp/)